# Faster way to get delta of 2 collections in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, collections, delta

I have a complete list of catalog inventory data in Mongo

The basic schema is:

- productSku (string)
- inventory (number)

This collection consists of approximately 14 million records.

I have another list of actively sold products with a similar schema.
Right now I have it as a json file.
It consists of approximately 23,000 records.

Every 5 hours the 14 million records updates with the latest inventory data.

Once that happens I need to create a CSV of the 23,000 product's latest inventory.

I'm doing it like this:

```
const inventoryModel = require('../data/inventoryModel');
const activeProducts = require('./activeProducts.json');

const inventoryUpdate = [];

for (const product of activeProducts) {
   let latest = await inventoryModel.findOne({ productSku: product.sku }).exec()
   latest = latest ? latest._doc : null;

   // If there's no current inventory record for the product 
   if (!lastest) {
       // If there was previously an inventory greater than 0
       if (product.inventory) {
          // Set the latest inventory to you
          inventoryUpdate.push({ sku: product.sku, inventory: 0 });
       }
   } else {
     // If there's a change in inventory
     if (latest.inventory != product.inventory) {
        inventoryUpdate.push({ sku: product.sku, inventory: latest.inventory });
     }
   }
}
```

This gives me an array **inventoryUpdate** that I can use to create a CSV for a mass update. This works fine but it's very slow. It takes about an hour to complete!

I was thinking about maybe adding **activeProducts** to *Mongo* as well and if I can somehow keep the execution of the logic within *Mongo* this would be a lot faster. If possible this is beyond my current understanding and ability.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you create an index on the `productSku` field ? Also, delete the `latest = latest ? latest._doc : null;` test, as it is redundant with the next test. Do not forget to access to inventory by `latest._doc.inventory`.

Comment: I do have an index on productSku, but since there's 14million in the collection and I'm querying it 23 thousand times it's very slow.

Comment: Maybe consider the sharding feature ?

Comment: I'm looking into moving activeProducts into Mongo and using $unionWith aggregate function. If I can get it to work I'll answer my own question I guess.

Comment: @mcanzerini I got it down to 5 seconds :)